# Different postfix logfile format when logging to separate file (maillog_file)

Tags: postfix, logging, syslog

In order to separate the mail logs from the general system logs, I added this line to `/etc/postfix/main.cf`

```
maillog_file = /var/log/postfix.log
```

As expected, a file `/var/log/postfix.log` is created, and there are no more `postfix` entries in the `var/log/syslog`. Unfortunately, it seems that this will also change the contents of the log entries. This is what I get in the `postfix.log` (changed my original domain name against `example.com` here)

```
May 23 17:33:15 example postfix/qmgr[662299]: E7DB742646: from=<mailer@example.com>, size=549252, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
May 23 17:33:15 example postfix/qmgr[662299]: D7DA646E85: removed
```

When changing it back (and I changed back and forth several times to be sure), and after sending the same email again, I get this in `syslog`.

```
May 23 17:33:52 example2020 postfix/smtp[664151]: DE7EA4265D: to=<mail@example.com>, relay=mail.example.com[11.111.11.111]:25, delay=1.7, delays=0.07/0.02/0.11/1.5, dsn=2.0.0,     status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 1BC7874B3A)
May 23 17:33:52 example2020 postfix/qmgr[664141]: DE7EA4265D: removed
```

Obviously, there are a lot of differences. First, a different server name is given after the date (`example` is set in `/etc/mailname`, `example2020` is specified in `/etc/hostname`). Second, only the `postfix/qmgr` entries are logged, but not the `postfix/smtp` that contain additional information. The same is true for the `var/log/mail.log` that does not receive these entries any more.

So, here are two question...

(1) Why does `postfix` (`mail_version = 3.4.13`) log different information (no more `postfix/smtp`) as soon as I specify a `maillog_file`?

(2) Any ideas how to tell `postfix` that I want my `postfix/smtp` information back?

### Postfix Configuration

```
$ postconf -n

alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
bounce_queue_lifetime = 24h
compatibility_level = 2
home_mailbox = Maildir/
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
maillog_file = /var/log/postfix.log   # This is the trouble maker
maximal_queue_lifetime = 36h
message_size_limit = 67108864
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 6
mydestination = example2020   # Host name replaced by "example"
myhostname = example.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8892
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
sender_canonical_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/senders
smtp_bind_address = 11.111.11.111
smtp_bind_address6 = 2a02:xxxx:0:xxxx::xx
smtp_destination_concurrency_limit = 3
smtp_tls_CApath = /etc/ssl/certs
smtp_tls_cert_file = /var/www/ssl/example.cert
smtp_tls_key_file = /var/www/ssl/example.key
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8892  # This one is for OpenDKIM
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /var/www/ssl/example.cert
smtpd_tls_exclude_ciphers = ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA
smtpd_tls_key_file = /var/www/ssl/example.key
smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers = high
smtpd_tls_mandatory_exclude_ciphers = ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
tls_high_cipherlist = EDH+CAMELLIA:EDH+aRSA:EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM:EECDH+aRSA+SHA384:EECDH+aRSA+SHA256:EECDH:+CAMELLIA256:+AES256:+CAMELLIA128:+AES128:+SSLv3:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!3DES:!MD5:!EXP:!PSK:!DSS:!RC4:!SEED:!ECDSA:CAMELLIA256-SHA:AES256-SHA:CAMELLIA128-SHA:AES128-SHA
tls_ssl_options = NO_COMPRESSION
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual


$ postconf -M

smtp       inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
pickup     unix  n       -       y       60      1       pickup
cleanup    unix  n       -       y       -       0       cleanup
qmgr       unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
tlsmgr     unix  -       -       y       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite    unix  -       -       y       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
defer      unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
trace      unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
verify     unix  -       -       y       -       1       verify
flush      unix  n       -       y       1000?   0       flush
proxymap   unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix  -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp       unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
relay      unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp -o syslog_name=postfix/$service_name
showq      unix  n       -       y       -       -       showq
error      unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
retry      unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
discard    unix  -       -       y       -       -       discard
local      unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual    unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp       unix  -       -       y       -       -       lmtp
anvil      unix  -       -       y       -       1       anvil
scache     unix  -       -       y       -       1       scache
postlog    unix-dgram n  -       n       -       1       postlogd
maildrop   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
uucp       unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
ifmail     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix - n       n       -       2       pipe flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py ${nexthop} ${user}
```

Comment: I *highly* recommend leaving logging formatting and decisions to your system logging daemon (rsyslog, systemd-journal, ..) and configuring tweaks there or in tools parsing their files. I *suspect* your problem lies with conflicting overrides rendering your alternate log destination ineffective, so please [share](https://serverfault.com/posts/1101621/edit) your configuration as [recommended in the tag](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/postfix).

Comment: Thanks for the hint about tag recommendations! I have added the configuration above. Regardings the recommendation to leave logging to the daemon ... I would, if there were not regulary reasons that would require me to store the mail logs (that include email addresses, i.e., personal data) separately from general system logs.

Comment: Have you fully restarted postfix? Because logging is configured via passed down ENV, a partial reload might create the appearance of postfix using new setting, but only because *some* of the services start logging there.

Comment: The restart is a good idea, but I do not think that it caused the issue: The server had done a full reboot before I had observed the "missing" log entries for postfix/smtp. After commenting out the `maillog_file` option and doing a `systemctl restart postfix`, new postfix/smtp entries were written to the `syslog` for new mails. And no more were written after re-enabling the option plus `systemctl restart postfix`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In order to separate the mail logs from the general system logs, I added this line to /etc/postfix/main.cf

This is not the best way, as @anx has commented, *highly recommend leaving logging formatting and decisions to your system logging daemon*.

For you information **rsylogd** already gathers postfix logs from the `/var/spool/postfix/dev/log` socket file (see inside `/etc/rsyslog.d/postfix.conf`) and this remains the cleanest way.

Have a look at your `/etc/rsyslog.conf` and there must be a line that looks like this:

```
*.*;mail,auth,authpriv.none     -/var/log/syslog
```

In order to tell **rsyslogd** not to write mail related log entries inside `/var/log/syslog`, change it to (note the **.none**):

```
*.*;mail.none,auth,authpriv.none        -/var/log/syslog
```

There is already a line that tells it to log all mail related things to `/var/log/mail.log` (change it to any file if you want) further down so you do not need to edit your postfix configuration file:

```
mail.*              -/var/log/mail.log
```

To answer your questions:

> (1) Why does postfix (mail_version = 3.4.13) log different information (no more postfix/smtp) as soon as I specify a maillog_file?

Your master.cf tells us you are using postfix in [chrooted mode](https://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/mail_systems/postfix_documentation/BASIC_CONFIGURATION_README_010.html). But your **qmgr** daemon is not chrooted so it can basically write in any log file unlike your **smtp** daemon.

> (2) Any ideas how to tell postfix that I want my postfix/smtp information back?

Your information is not gone but many of your daemons cannot break the chroot so they cannot directly write in `/var/log/postfix.log` as you intend.
An option would be un-chrooting them by switching the **chroot** column to **n** in your master.cf but again, no sane people would recommend that.

CONCLUSION: Your best and safest option is tweaking your **rsylogd** configuration as  described earlier.

Comment: This explains how to do it with rsyslog, but I don't think this explains why the original approach does not work. Check the `postlog unix-dgram` line in `master.cf`, that looks correct and should forward logging for chrooted services.

Comment: Postfix `3.4.13` sounds like a version someone using a Debian(-derivative) would use (someone directly tracking upstream stable 3.4.x would use `3.4.24` by now), so while logs might be passed to `rsyslogd`, there would still exist additional persistent log storage via `systemd-journald`.

Comment: Very elaborate answer, thank you! For those seeking the same answer, I would like to ad that the respective line may be found in `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf` and that there may not be an explicit `mail`, but adding `mail.none` in the line with `-/var/log/syslog` works exactly as specified in the answer.